# Jenkins - Compile source into jarfile, use as artifact

Tags: java, jar, jenkins, continuous-integration, artifacts

I need to allow Jenkins to, after building, create a .jar of the sources downloaded from the Subversion, and allow users to download that as an artifact. Here's an example of a site with this feature:

https://jenkins.kellerkindt.com/job/ShowCaseStandalone/

After building, it compiles "ShowCaseStandalone.jar", and that is added to the artifacts, where people can download it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your build process work?

Comment: It just builds when the SVN repo connects to /job/<job>/build?key=<auth key>

Comment: There's no build/post-build steps (currently)

Comment: Let me rephrase that - how have _you_ made Jenkins invoke javac on your source?

Comment: I don't think it does; it most likely just takes files from the SVN, and creates a build. I'm extremely new to Continuous Integration, or Jenkins, more specifically.

Comment: Jenkins in itself does not know very much about Java sources but knows how to invoke ant or Maven and collect the results. Is your current build procedure - invoked by Jenkins - based on ant or maven?

Comment: Currently, it uses nothing. I'm enabling ant right now, and we'll see how this goes...

Comment: So you type `javac` from the command Line every time you edit your source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually solved this...
I realized I wasn't actually using Ant, so I had to do that, and I then had used Archive the Artifacts, as @Nick said.

Comment: Could you add your solution? That would help others (like me) who are facing the same issue.

Comment: @AlastorMoody I just had to add the ant component in Jenkins. There's many easy tutorials to do this on Google.

Answer (score 0):

In the post build step in the configuration for your project, you can add a "Archive the Artifacts" as an action.  Type in the name of the artifacts you want to display.